# CIFilter for CategoryDistortionEffect example

Tags: iphone, filter, distortion

Can someone show an example of initializing the CIFilter for kCICategoryDistortionEffect?

I need to create Distortion effect for my photography. I have read that it is possible, with CIFilter in IOS 5. 
But I can not find a suitable code how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for this to.  Thus far it appears that's not available in iOS 5.  Here's the evidence:

If you execute:

```
NSArray *properties = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:
                       kCICategoryBuiltIn];
```

you'll see that it only returns the following list which *doesn't* contain any of the kCICategoryDistortionEffect's.  It only contains:

```
CIAdditionCompositing,
CIAffineTransform,
CICheckerboardGenerator,
CIColorBlendMode,
CIColorBurnBlendMode,
CIColorControls,
CIColorCube,
CIColorDodgeBlendMode,
CIColorInvert,
CIColorMatrix,
CIColorMonochrome,
CIConstantColorGenerator,
CICrop,
CIDarkenBlendMode,
CIDifferenceBlendMode,
CIExclusionBlendMode,
CIExposureAdjust,
CIFalseColor,
CIGammaAdjust,
CIGaussianGradient,
CIHardLightBlendMode,
CIHighlightShadowAdjust,
CIHueAdjust,
CIHueBlendMode,
CILightenBlendMode,
CILinearGradient,
CILuminosityBlendMode,
CIMaximumCompositing,
CIMinimumCompositing,
CIMultiplyBlendMode,
CIMultiplyCompositing,
CIOverlayBlendMode,
CIRadialGradient,
CISaturationBlendMode,
CIScreenBlendMode,
CISepiaTone,
CISoftLightBlendMode,
CISourceAtopCompositing,
CISourceInCompositing,
CISourceOutCompositing,
CISourceOverCompositing,
CIStraightenFilter,
CIStripesGenerator,
CITemperatureAndTint,
CIToneCurve,
CIVibrance,
CIVignette,
CIWhitePointAdjust
```

and is missing the one's we're interested in:

```
CICategoryDistortionEffect,
CIBumpDistortion,
CIBumpDistortionLinear,
CICircleSplashDistortion,
CICircularWrap,
CIDisplacementDistortion,
CIGlassDistortion,
CIGlassLozenge,
CIHoleDistortion,
CIPinchDistortion,
CITorusLensDistortion,
CITwirlDistortion,
CIVortexDistortion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the filter types by using below code

```
NSArray *filterNames =[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn];
NSLog(@"Built in filters");
for (NSString *currentFilterName in filterNames)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", currentFilterName);
}
```